# How to comment EJS code in WebStorm by shortcut?

Tags: comments, webstorm, ejs

When I press `Cmd + /` then it looks like this.

[image]

Is there any way to comment all the block that I want to make it as a comment by `one shortcut` in WebStorm?

I heard VS Code can manage this problem. I just want to know if there is way to figure this out in WebStorm.

Answer (score 1):

No; please follow [WEB-27157](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27157) for updates